# Test fetch then catch in a thunk using jest

Tags: react-redux, jestjs

I have a thunk function to fetch image using remote url and upload it to a server. The thunk function is working as expected but I am not able to test the fetch then catch chain here using jest.

```js
export function fetchAndUploadImageThunk({ id, imageSelected }) {
  return async () => {
    const fileName = imageSelected.get('title');
    const mimeType = imageSelected.get('type');
    await fetch(imageSelected.get('url'), { mode: 'cors', credentials: 'include' })
      .then(async (response) => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error(response);
        }
        const responseBlob = response.blob();
        const file = new File([responseBlob], fileName, { type: mimeType });
        const uploadHandler = new UploadHandler({ onFail: () => {} });
        await uploadHandler.uploadFile({
          file,
          fileNewName: fileName,
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        throw new Error(error);
      });
  };
}
```

I have already tried testing using following code:

```js
test('fetchAndUploadImageThunk uploads file', async () => {
  global.fetch = jest.fn().mockImplementation(
    () => {
      const p = new Promise((resolve) => {
        resolve({
          blob: () => 'blob',
        });
      });
      return p;
    }
  );
  const onFail = jest.fn();
  rewireUtil.mockDependencies({
    onFail,
  });
  const thunk = fetchAndUploadImageThunk({
    id: 34,
    imageSelected: Immutable.fromJS({
      title: 'title1',
      url: 'http://www.url1.com',
      type: 'image/png',
    }),
  });
  await thunk(() => {}, () => {}, obj => Promise.resolve(obj));
  expect(global.fetch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  global.fetch.mockClear();
  delete global.fetch;
});
```

but somehow it's not getting passed.

Expected result is to have a function that can test the above thunk call with `uploadFile` getting called with right arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the unit test solution:

`index.ts`:

```js
import UploadHandler from './UploadHandler';

export function fetchAndUploadImageThunk({ id, imageSelected }) {
  return async () => {
    const fileName = imageSelected.get('title');
    const mimeType = imageSelected.get('type');
    await fetch(imageSelected.get('url'), { mode: 'cors', credentials: 'include' })
      .then(async response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error('fetch image error');
        }
        const responseBlob = await response.blob();
        const file = new File([responseBlob], fileName, { type: mimeType });
        const uploadHandler = new UploadHandler({ onFail: () => {} });
        await uploadHandler.uploadFile({
          file,
          fileNewName: fileName
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        throw new Error(error);
      });
  };
}
```

`UploadHandler.ts`:

```js
export default class UploadHandler {
  constructor(opts) {}

  public async uploadFile(opt) {
    console.log('uploadFile');
  }
}
```

`index.spec.ts`:

```js
import { fetchAndUploadImageThunk } from './';
import UploadHandler from './UploadHandler';

jest.mock('./UploadHandler.ts', () => {
  const mUploadHandler = {
    uploadFile: jest.fn()
  };
  return jest.fn(() => mUploadHandler);
});

const uploadHandler = new UploadHandler({});

describe('fetchAndUploadImageThunk', () => {
  let mImageSelected;
  beforeEach(() => {
    mImageSelected = {
      get: jest.fn(name => {
        switch (name) {
          case 'title':
            return 'ebod666.mp4';
          case 'type':
            return 'mp4';
          case 'url':
            return 'https://github.com/mrdulin';
        }
      })
    };
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });
  it('should upload file success', async () => {
    const id = 1;
    const thunk = fetchAndUploadImageThunk({ id, imageSelected: mImageSelected });
    const mBlob = new Blob();
    const mFile = new File([mBlob], 'ebod666.mp4');
    const mResponseBlob = jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce(mBlob);
    (global as any).fetch = jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce({ ok: true, blob: mResponseBlob } as any);
    (global as any).File = jest.fn().mockImplementation((...opts: any) => {
      return mFile;
    });

    await thunk();
    expect((global as any).fetch).toBeCalledWith('https://github.com/mrdulin', {
      mode: 'cors',
      credentials: 'include'
    });
    expect((global as any).File).toBeCalledWith([mBlob], 'ebod666.mp4', { type: 'mp4' });
    expect(uploadHandler.uploadFile).toBeCalledWith({ file: mFile, fileNewName: 'ebod666.mp4' });
  });

  it('should throw error when response is not ok', async () => {
    const id = 1;
    const thunk = fetchAndUploadImageThunk({ id, imageSelected: mImageSelected });
    (global as any).fetch = jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce({ ok: false } as any);
    await expect(thunk()).rejects.toThrowError('Error: fetch image error');
    expect((global as any).fetch).toBeCalledWith('https://github.com/mrdulin', {
      mode: 'cors',
      credentials: 'include'
    });
  });

  it('should throw error when fetch error', async () => {
    const id = 1;
    const thunk = fetchAndUploadImageThunk({ id, imageSelected: mImageSelected });
    (global as any).fetch = jest.fn().mockRejectedValueOnce(new Error('network error'));
    await expect(thunk()).rejects.toThrowError('network error');
    expect((global as any).fetch).toBeCalledWith('https://github.com/mrdulin', {
      mode: 'cors',
      credentials: 'include'
    });
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
PASS  src/stackoverflow/57614415/index.spec.ts (6.983s)
  fetchAndUploadImageThunk
    ✓ should upload file success (9ms)
    ✓ should throw error when response is not ok (4ms)
    ✓ should throw error when fetch error (3ms)

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |      100 |      100 |    83.33 |      100 |                   |
 index.ts |      100 |      100 |    83.33 |      100 |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       3 passed, 3 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        8.052s, estimated 9s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/57614415